# Qual a origem da palavra "pagode"?

Tags: etimologia

Qual a origem da palavra *"pagode"* (o estilo de musica brasileira)? Sei que tem suas origens no Rio de Janeiro, e sei também que aqui na Bahia a maioria do povo gosta muito.

Comment: Os dicionários dizem que o nome "pagode" vem do templo oriental [pagode](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagode_(templo)) por meio de alguma língua dravídica, provavelmente o Tâmil. Não sei como o nome de um templo budista originou num gênero musical afrobrasileiro. Porém, há um terceiro sentido da palavra "pagode", que significa "bagunça, diversão ruidosa, festança". **Talvez** este sentido seja o intermediário: As manifestações naqueles templos eram ruidosas, daí os colonizadores portugueses, que conheciam a Índia, usaram do mesmo termo para se referir às festas dos escravos. **Talvez**.

Comment: Portugal tinha algumas cidades e portos na costa da Índia como colônias, principalmente no sul do país e na ilha de Sri Lanka (regiões em preto no [mapa](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Portuguese_India.PNG)), e são justamente nessas regiões onde o Tâmil e as demais línguas dravídicas são faladas. A palavra "pagode" veio daí. Estou respondendo tua pergunta como comentário pois, mesmo sabendo de onde veio, não sei como essa palavra se transformou no sentido que você se refere. Eu só levantei uma hipótese no meu comentário anterior, mas é um achismo sem qualquer fundamento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelas pesquisas que fiz, acredito que o significado realmente tenha relação com celebrações religiosas ocorridas no Oriente e observadas pelos Portuguêses aqui no Brasil. Segundo o site [samba-choro](https://web.archive.org/web/20050302090453/http://www.samba-choro.com.br/s-c/tribuna/samba-choro.0102/0532.html) que cita o Dicionário Etimológico
Nova Fronteira, essa é a Etimologia da palavra pagode:

> Pagode (sm) - ídolo indiano(1525) Templo hindu;  por  extensão,
> mesquita de mouros, varela de budistas.  1516 - Antiga moeda de ouro
> hindu; 1595 - Festa  ruidosa, folia. Do sânscrito.

Ainda, segundo o site [Sua Língua](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/04/29/pagode/), explica uma origem bem parecida:

> infelizmente, como estudioso da linguagem eu nada posso decidir; posso
> apenas descrever e, se a sorte me ajudar, posso até entender o que se
> passa em nosso idioma. No caso do pagode, deves ficar orgulhoso com
> tua filha, pois ela é quem está com a razão.  A palavra foi
> introduzida nas línguas ocidentais pelos nossos avós portugueses, que
> foram buscá-la em suas andanças pelos portos do Oriente. Como nós a
> empregamos como uma denominação genérica de templo budista, costumamos
> associá-la ao Japão ou a China; no entanto, a maioria dos
> especialistas pensa que ela veio de uma língua da Índia, ou do
> sânscrito ou do dravídico. Alguns etimologistas delirantes vêem em
> pagode uma legítima palavra vernácula, derivada de pagão; seria,
> portanto, um termo depreciativo que os portugueses formaram para
> denominar todo e qualquer templo não-cristão. Um destes malucos ainda
> foi mais longe (e por acaso há limites para a loucura?): pagode seria
> a aglutinação de pagan god (“deus pagão”, em Inglês). Essas hipóteses,
> no entanto, são destruídas pelo testemunho de inúmeros viajantes
> ocidentais, que registraram, pessoalmente, o uso da palavra no Sul da
> Ásia. Há algo, contudo, nessas teorias que não deve ser desprezado: a
> antiga animosidade para com as religiões não-cristãs. Na realidade,
> tanto o pagode, quanto a sinagoga — templos que automaticamente nos
> evocam o budismo e o judaísmo — adquiriram, já no Português do séc.
> XVI, o significado secundário de “barulho, confusão” (como na frase
> “Ele armou o maior pagode“) ou “festa ruidosa, festança popular” (como
> em “Fomos a um pagode na casa do Dorinho”). Para Houaiss, daí foi um
> pequeno passo para designar o tipo de samba de partido alto,
> introduzido no Rio de Janeiro na década de 70. Como vês, foi um longo
> trajeto da Ásia dos descobrimentos ao morro carioca do final do séc.
> XX. Abraço. Prof. Moreno

Comment: [Neste livro](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=lgv7PDOJfXgC&pg=PA42&dq=pagode&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiozdDZgL7XAhVFGJAKHdR9C9EQ6AEIUjAI#v=onepage&q=pagode&f=false), que relata a estadia do arcebispo de Goa (capital da colônia portuguesa nas Índias), o autor fala dos pagodes, das multidões que peregrinavam a tais prédios e das festas realizadas lá. É um livro bem antigo, de 1606, e une os dois termos: o concreto original ("templo pagão") com um pouco do outro ("festa pagã"). Não achei outros usos de "pagode" só como "festa", i.e., sem se referir nem ao templo nem às reuniões dos escravos.

Answer (score 3):

O nome pagode tem origem no sâncristo em um idioma dravídico  (malaiala pagódi, tumul pagódi) Em 1525 aparece na língua portuguesa como ídolo indiano e templo hindu. Da língua portuguesa passou para as demais línguas europeias. Em 1595 já tinha o sentido de festa ruidosa, folia, certamente pela influência dos navegadores portugueses à Índia. Mas o termo pagão, que vem do latim paganus, deu origem, no século XIV às paganálias, destas de aldeias em honra de Ceres. Em 1899 surge um termo pagodento, amigo dos pagodes, pagão, e uma pagodice era sinônimo de feitiço. Portanto acho que houve uma fusão de dois nomes, um pela influência indiana e o outro vindo do latim. O sentido que temos hoje vem do latim, de festa pagã. Mas o nome só surge com as navegações portuguesas às índias.

Answer (score -2):

Pagode dos antepassados da minha mãe, era o mesmo que forro, e até hoje no interior de Minas forro é para eles o mesmo que forro

Comment: Queres dizer *forró*, certo? Mas isso não explica a origem de *pagode*.